# Уведомление по нажатию кнопки

Tags: android, firebase, уведомления, android-notification

В приложение есть несколько кнопок, по нажатию которых выскакивается уведомление. Как это реализовать? Плюс еще хочется приложение совместить с Firebase. Чтобы уведомление отправлялось каждому пользователю, который скачал приложение.

Answer (score 0):

с `Firebase` совмещать довольно просто. Добавляете зависимости в свой проект и с консоли файрбейс просто создаете `Notification`. А по поводу нажатия кнопок то вам подойдет обычные уведомления

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
       new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
               .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
               .setContentTitle("Title")
               .setContentText("Notification text");

Notification notification = builder.build();

NotificationManager notificationManager =
       (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

---

тут подробнее:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=ru

и тут разжевано:

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/509-android-notifications-osnovy.html

Comment: А другие пользователи смогут видеть мои уведомления, если я буду нажимать на кнопку ??

Comment: А другие пользователи смогут видеть мои уведомления, если я буду нажимать на кнопку ??

Comment: Не будут. Это локальный пуш.

Comment: А есть же такие приложения, где например пользователь хочет добавить кого-то в друзья и у второго пользователя появляется уведомление о запросе в друзья.

Comment: Для этого вам нужен сервер. И настраивать общение с сервером.

Comment: Firebase не подойдет для этого?

Comment: Все зависит от того что вам нужно.   https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

Comment: ну я об этом написал в вопросе. Просто нужно отправить push уведомления всей группе со сматрфона, а не с консоли firebase.